# How to get Sagemaker Batch Transform Job status printed out in my python notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a python notebook which is initiating a Batch Transform Job in Sagemaker. However, I want to also print the status "Failed", "In Progress" and "Completed" once the job is complete running. As of now, I am only able to start the Batch Transform Job (rf=random forest) but I am not certain how to get the job status print outs. Can someone help with that given my script below?

[image]

```
rf_transformer = rf.transformer(
                                instance_count,
                                instance_type,
                                strategy=strategy,
                                output_path=output_path,
                                max_payload=max_payload)

rf_transformer.transform(
                                str('s3://batch_scoring/rf_output),
                                content_type='text/csv',
                                compression_type='Gzip'
                         )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with:

```py
job_name = rf_transformer.latest_transform_job.name
rf_transformer.sagemaker_session.describe_transform_job(job_name)['TransformJobStatus']
```

You can also use the AWS SDK directly, if you wish:

```py
import boto3

sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
sagemaker_client.describe_transform_job(job_name)['TransformJobStatus']
```

API documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTransformJob.html